# c# Mongodb 2.0 driver get UpdateManyAsync result

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Is there any way to get the updated collections after/before the update?
What I can think of is pretty heavy.

1. get what i want to update using filter.
2. update everything i got in the previous state
3. get all by ids again and check what has been updated.

Why I need this?

I have a service which constantly fetch data from the database.
I want it to take stuff atomically depending on the status they have.

For example, if a document, which contains the field Status, has a status of 1 i want the service to fetch it and atomically change it to 2 in the process, so every other component wont override me for some reason.

Update looks like:

```
var filter = Builders<ServiceModel>.Filter.And(
                                                                Builders<ServiceModel>.Filter.Gt(t => t.EndDate, dueDate),
                                                                Builders<ServiceModel>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Status, Enums.ServiceHandleStatus.Registered));

            var update = Builders<ServiceModel>.Update.Set(t => t.Status, Enums.ServiceHandleStatus.InProcess);

            var options = new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = false };

            using (var result = this.manager.Trainings.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options))
```

Any direction?

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only atomic updates in mongodb like this is to use findAndModify, which is presented in .NET as FindOneAndUpdate. So, you can do what you want, but only a single document at a time.

**Update**

If you are ok making multiple requests, you can do this in 2 requests using UpdateMany and, instead of just marking them as InProcess, also indicate which process is processing them. Then, you can make a subsequent query to come back and pull all of those that are InProcess for the current process.

The only problem with that is you can't indicate to only update 10, or 20, or 10K, which means you can't scale out to multiple "processors" because you'll be updating *all* of them.

Comment: So if, for example, i want to get collections in a decent rate of 10k-20k per minute. What is ur suggestion? Its too bad if i have to send 20k single requests, dont u think?

Comment: What do you think will be better, my 3-phases way or getting them 1 by 1 thrn?

Comment: You'll have to test and see. It completely depends on use case. However, doing phases 1 and 2 separately will lead to multiple "processors" grabbing the same documents. Hence, you need to combine 1 and 2 as I mentioned in my updated answer. If you want to support multiple "processors", you'll need to go 1 by 1 with FindOneAndUpdate.